# 1С-Битрикс и непонятки с слэшами в URL

Tags: url, битрикс

Не знаю даже, как сформулировать проблему. В общем, у человека есть сайт на Bitrix, и проблема в том, что если поставить в конце URL слэш, то пишет, что такого каталога не существует. С Bitrix работаю первый раз. Как сформулировать запрос поисковику - я не знаю. Он вообще игнорирует все слова, кроме bitrix и выдает совершенно не то. Если кто-то знает, в чем проблема и как это вообще можно обозвать - отзовитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, в общем, у тебя где-то есть там multileve. Вот ему можешь вызвать там такой метод `$multilevel->checkLastSlash(true)`. Тогда он сам будет убирать лишний слеш.